# Easier Way to VLOOKUP to the left w/ IMPORTRANGE?

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, array-formulas

I'm using a formula in Google Sheets that combines vlookup and importrange to look to the left in a separate spreadsheet. Here's the formula...

```
={
  "Staff Name";
  arrayformula(
    iferror(
      VLOOKUP(
        A2:A,
        {
          IMPORTRANGE("1Ri5k_WNei8X9XJVWxrblSuEKS3680YcH3LobflvmzuALcsY","Directory!D2:D"),
          IMPORTRANGE("1Ri5k_WNei8X9XJVWxrblSuEKS3680YcH3LobflvmzuALcsY","Directory!C2:C")
        },
        2,
        0
      ),
      ""
    )
  )
}
```

But, let's say I need to look 6 columns to the left, instead of just 2. Do I need to do an importrange for every single column like the above formula? Or is there an easier way?

In other words, will my formula need to change to look like this below?

```
={
  "Staff Name";
  arrayformula(
    iferror(
      VLOOKUP(
        A2:A,
        {
          IMPORTRANGE("1Ri5k_WNei8X9XJVWxrblSuEKS3680YcH3LobflvmzuALcsY","Directory!H2:H"),
          IMPORTRANGE("1Ri5k_WNei8X9XJVWxrblSuEKS3680YcH3LobflvmzuALcsY","Directory!G2:G"),
          IMPORTRANGE("1Ri5k_WNei8X9XJVWxrblSuEKS3680YcH3LobflvmzuALcsY","Directory!F2:F"),
          IMPORTRANGE("1Ri5k_WNei8X9XJVWxrblSuEKS3680YcH3LobflvmzuALcsY","Directory!E2:E"),
          IMPORTRANGE("1Ri5k_WNei8X9XJVWxrblSuEKS3680YcH3LobflvmzuALcsY","Directory!D2:D"),
          IMPORTRANGE("1Ri5k_WNei8X9XJVWxrblSuEKS3680YcH3LobflvmzuALcsY","Directory!C2:C")
        },
        6,
        0
      ),
      ""
    )
  )
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Your "let's say" scenario is not clear. Could you be specific with your example (i.e., "I want to use the source range J2:J as the primary VLOOKUP column and return source column(s) ________________________")?

Comment: @ErikTyler I edited my post to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Spencer, it is still not clear what you want to return. You've got something in the local sheet in A2:A. What is that information (or at least its data type)? And you want to look up each of those entries from A2:A up within Column ... H? ... of the remote sheet? Correct? And then you want the formula to return the data (a name) from Column ... C? ... of the remote sheet? Or do you want to return ALL the data from Columns H, G, F, E, D, C of the remote sheet in that reverse order?

Comment: @Spencer why not just import `Directory!H2:H` and `Directory!C2:C`? The formula will be exactly as your first one, but with different first range.